# HP Probook 6540b with dual screens using DisplayPort and VGA

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, displayport

Is it possible to use the DisplayPort and VGA output at the same time to run two screens.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything in the manual for that model that says yes or no. It **should** be possible.

If it's anything like a few of the laptops I have been dealing with lately you should be able to either have the laptop screen and one external monitor or two external monitors (but not the laptop screen) going.

Comment: ... and I only just noticed how old this question is.